# kafka container - Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm following [this guide](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity) in order to start a single kafka container .I'm working on win10 pro and my cli is gitbash.

docker-compose-single-broker.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka 
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

The containers are starting without any problem :

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-single-broker.yml up -d
Creating kafka-docker_zookeeper_1 ... done
Creating kafka-docker_kafka_1     ... done

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
19929c6c3297        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         17 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                               kafka-docker_kafka_1
d343a8ecf7ed        wurstmeister/zookeeper   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   17 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafka-docker_zookeeper_1
```

However, when I try to run any kafka command(create topic,list topics) from inside the container like the following :

```
> $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server `broker-list.sh`
> $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic test --bootstrap-server `broker-list.sh`
```

I'm getting the following warnings and afterwards a timeout exception :

```
$ ./start-kafka-shell.sh localhost
bash-4.4# $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server `broker-list.sh`
[2020-06-09 11:47:26,241] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/172.17.54.145:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-06-09 11:47:29,306] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/172.17.54.145:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

The content of the start-kafka-shell.sh :

```
$ cat start-kafka-shell.sh
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e HOST_IP=$1 -e ZK=$2 -i -t wurstmeister/kafka /bin/bash
```

Comment: Using your exact Docker Compose and running the commands in the Kafka container as described works just fine for me. Are you definitely running these commands from within the Kafka broker machine?

Comment: Any chance u arent working on windows ? or using a different docker version ?

Comment: I am working on a Mac. Please can you update your question to show how you are running the commands in docker, e.g. `docker exec`

Comment: I added that, please look on the main post

Comment: You don't need to mount the Docker socket...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `start-kafka-shell.sh` is. If you're using Docker then you can interact with it from your Windows shell as follows:

```
docker exec -it tmp_kafka_1 bash -c '$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test4 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server `broker-list.sh`'


docker exec -it tmp_kafka_1 bash -c '$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic test4 --bootstrap-server `broker-list.sh`'

Topic: test4    PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: test4    Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

You just need the correct Docker container name (`tmp_kafka_1` in my example above), which you can confirm with `docker ps`.

Comment: The start-kafka-shell.sh just attaches my cli to to the container`s shell. I added to the post its content.When I run what u suggested I'm getting the same output . Maybe related to the fact that I'm working on windows ?

Comment: What about if you run `docker exec -it tmp_kafka_1 bash -c '$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test4 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092'` ?

Comment: exactly the same :( I can reproduce the error whenever I want (from scratch) if that is usefull..

Comment: An important note, when I try to produce and consume from localhost:9200 I succeed (tried with java libraries..)

Comment: I'd be inclined to try this then: https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html

Comment: The start script is in the wurstmeister repo